# Validating a form on a button click in struts 1.2

Tags: validation, struts

I am trying to validate user credentials details during application log in.I have changed my struts config and validation xml but the validation gets invoked on the page load itself.
I want that this validation should be invoked only during the click of a button(submit button).
My struts config is as under:

```
<action-mappings>

    <action attribute="loginForm" input="jsp/LoginPage.jsp" name="loginForm"
        parameter="method" path="/loginAction" scope="request"
        type="com.pcs.bpems.portal.struts.action.LoginAction" validate="false">
        <forward name="schoolloginpage" path="/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp" />

    </action>

    <action attribute="loginForm" input="/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp" name="loginForm"
        parameter="method" path="/loginAction" scope="request"
        type="com.pcs.bpems.portal.struts.action.LoginAction" validate="true">
        <forward name="schoolloginpage" path="/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp" />
        <forward name="schoolhomepage" path="/ownerHome.do?method=showHome" />
    </action>
```

My validation xml is as under

```
<form name="loginForm">
   <field property="userId" depends="required,minlength">
    <arg0 key="label.userName"/>        
     <var>
         <var-name>minlength</var-name> 
        <var-value>6</var-value> 
     </var>
      <arg1 key="${var:minlength}"  resource="false" />
  </field>
  <field property="password" depends="required,minlength">
    <arg0 key="label.password"/>        
     <var>
        <var-name>minlength</var-name> 
        <var-value>6</var-value> 
     </var>
      <arg1 key="${var:minlength}"  resource="false" />
 </field>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

@Anish Try this code instead of your first LoginAction attribute,

```
<action path="/loginAction" parameter="method" 
    type="com.pcs.bpems.portal.struts.action.LoginAction" validate="false">
 <forward name="schoolloginpage" path="/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp" />
</action>
```

My thought is form name is not necessary for load the form, though you are made validate attribute to false. Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not pass through the `input`, Struts performs the validation. There are several ways to solve it.

#### Request directly to the JSP

Make a request to the JSP file **directly** and not through the `org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet`.

```
http://localhost:8080/MyContext/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp
```

#### With a `forward`

```
<action path="/login" forward="/jsp/SchoolLoginPage.jsp" />
```

Use:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyContext/login.do
```